# tabularx: why the difference in formatting lists in cells

Tags: tabularx, itemize, enumitem

please consider *mwe* bellow:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                      wide,%leftmargin = *,
                      before     = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
                      after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                        }
                           }% end of AtBeginEnvironment

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{15mm} L L L
                             @{}}
\toprule
    &
    Integration of heterogeneous data &
    Algorithms to identify urban features &
    Improve accuracy for spectral classification algorithms \\
\midrule
    Objective &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   Improve the spatial and spectral resolution
    \item   Enhance the ability of features detection and display
    \item   Promote the geometric precision
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   Accelerate future processing and improve classification accuracy
    \item   Automated processes for detecting, extracting, simulating, classifying and modelling urban features
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   Capability of separating urban land-cover and land-use classes in an adequate manner
    \end{itemize}       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\hsize=0.4\hsize}L
                            *{3}{>{\hsize=1.2\hsize}L}
                            @{}}
\toprule
    &
    Integration of heterogeneous data &
    Algorithms to identify urban features &
    Improve accuracy for spectral classification algorithms \\
\midrule
    Objective &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   Improve the spatial and spectral resolution
    \item   Enhance the ability of features detection and display
    \item   Promote the geometric precision
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   Accelerate future processing and improve classification accuracy
    \item   Automated processes for detecting, extracting, simulating, classifying and modelling urban features
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   Capability of separating urban land-cover and land-use classes in an adequate manner
    \end{itemize}       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

as we can see, in both cases, the width of the columns is the same. Why is the formatting of the lists different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Setting `\hsize` directly is of course not a latex supported thing to do, and it means that any nested list structure doesn't know how wide it is supposed to be, setting `\linewidth` to the new `\hsize` gets things back on track.

The `tabularx` documentation should perhaps document this, although it does actually document that all `X` columns have to be the same width unless you break the rules.....

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                      wide,%leftmargin = *,
                      before     = \vspace{-\baselineskip},
                      after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                        }
                           }% end of AtBeginEnvironment

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} p{15mm} L L L
                             @{}}
\toprule
    &
    Integration of heterogeneous data &
    Algorithms to identify urban features &
    Improve accuracy for spectral classification algorithms \\
\midrule
    Objective &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   Improve the spatial and spectral resolution
    \item   Enhance the ability of features detection and display
    \item   Promote the geometric precision
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   Accelerate future processing and improve classification accuracy
    \item   Automated processes for detecting, extracting, simulating, classifying and modelling urban features
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   Capability of separating urban land-cover and land-use classes in an adequate manner
    \end{itemize}       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\hsize=0.4\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}L
                            *{3}{>{\hsize=1.2\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}L}
                            @{}}
\toprule
    &
    Integration of heterogeneous data &
    Algorithms to identify urban features &
    Improve accuracy for spectral classification algorithms \\
\midrule
    Objective &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   Improve the spatial and spectral resolution
    \item   Enhance the ability of features detection and display
    \item   Promote the geometric precision
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   Accelerate future processing and improve classification accuracy
    \item   Automated processes for detecting, extracting, simulating, classifying and modelling urban features
    \end{itemize}
    &
    \begin{itemize}
    \item   Capability of separating urban land-cover and land-use classes in an adequate manner
    \end{itemize}       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

To get exactly the same linebreaks You can use

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\hsize=.406\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}L
                            *{3}{>{\hsize=1.198\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}L}
                            @{}}
```

Comment: thank you very much for answer. it help me a lot! now i have only one wish: please, when you will have some spare time, add this explanation and solution to `tabularx`  documentation.

Comment: @Zarko  `$ svn commit -m "adjust linewidth as well as hsize in documentation example" tabularx.dtx changes.txt 
Sending        changes.txt
Sending        tabularx.dtx
Transmitting file data ..done
Committing transaction...
Committed revision 1517.`